# For loop, if and else, dont want to create whitespace between the prints

Tags: python, whitespace

I'm writing a script like the following:

In the input for text, I'll write a word, and if the letter in that word is `abcde` it will just print the letter, else its going to print the letter + `o`and then the letter again.

For the result right now, I get (for example the text = allan), "a lil lil a nin".

I want the result to be: "alillilanin".

How do I remove the whitespace?

```
def sprak(text):
    bok = "abcde"
    for letter in text:   
        if letter in bok == bok:
            print letter,
        elif letter != bok:
            print letter+"u"+letter,


text = raw_input("what word ")
sprak(text)
```

Comment: What does `if letter in bok == bok:` mean to you? I'm not convinced it would mean the same to Python.

Comment: Please edit your question: the example you give does not match your code.

Comment: ye nevermind dont know what i did there, removed the last "== bok" part, so its now if letter in bok:

Comment: @user3036505 Instead of editing your post to note the problem is solved, could you [mark the answer that helped you (if one did) as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)?

Answer (score 1):

Just do not use `print`, try this:

```
def sprak(text):
    bok = "abcde"
    for letter in text:   
        if letter in bok == bok:
            sys.stdout.write(letter)
        elif letter != bok:
            sys.stdout.write(letter + "u" + letter)
```

Comment: not sure if i follow you, does that print the text? anyway i get NameError: global name 'sys' is not defined

Comment: @user3036505 You need to `import sys` to use `sys` calls.

Comment: thank you mister, working great now

Answer (score 0):

You would need Python v3 `print` function for that. You would need to import that function first by

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Now, to suppress the whitespace separator between items.

```
print(letter + 'u' + letter, sep='')
```

& to also suppress the endline terminator do

```
print(letter, sep='', end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct a string and print once:

```
output_str = ''
for letter in text:   
    if letter in bok == bok:
        output_str += letter,
    elif letter != bok:
        output_str += letter+"u"+letter
print output_str
```